# Accidentally restored Windows 10 computer back to W7 - can I get another free upgrade to W10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I wanted to reset a rather old Windows 10 computer, so used the Windows 10 reset option. This resulted in an endless boot loop, and while trying to fix this I found a backup and restore method from Dell. I tried that, it worked, but it turns out that the computer is now back to Windows 7 Professional. My guess is that it was a free update to Windows 10.

NB: I don't have the W7 key, and the sticker on the side is unreadable.

Is is possible to do another upgrade to Windows 10? Can I prove somehow that this computer had an update before? Will an upgrade or fresh W10 install destroy the recovery partition from Dell?

Comment: You still have your Windows 10 license. You just have to install Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tested this solution because this never happened to me, but I know that Windows 10 activation for PC which benefited from the free Windows 10 upgrade is automatic, since it is linked to the hardware.

So, I recommend you use the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool to download a fresh copy of Windows 10, [available here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Then you can clean install it on your machine, and when you connect to internet after the install it will activate automatically.

Comment: Will I need the W7 key for this? And will this destroy the recovery part from Dell?

Comment: No and No......

Comment: I did the installation and it worked without needing a key.